# Set image within ion-grid column. i.e. 50% of total height of the page

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ionic4

*.html*

```
<ion-content class="content">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="row1">
      <ion-col size="12">
         <ion-img [src]="data?.path" class="image"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="row2">     

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
.content {
    ion-grid {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .row1 {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .row2 {
        flex: 1;
    }
    ion-img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

*result*

[image]

**Q:** I need to contain the image within `50%` level. But it does not work like that. But without an image, it is working fine. i.e. It keeps `50%` top and bottom section. Any clue?

I tried this:

```
 ion-img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
```

*Debug:*

[image]

Comment: use `height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100%;`

Comment: Like so? `ion-img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }` @TemaniAfif

Comment: no, for the ion-grid

Comment: nevermind, it seems not an issue, but your HTML isn't enough to know this

Comment: yes, you have the same output as here, so using vh will not fix your issue. I thought it was related to the use of % ... there is also a lot of nested element which make this a bit tricky. try adding max-height:100% to the parent element of the image

Comment: Still no luck? @TemaniAfif https://i.imgur.com/Bpjf4Z3.png

Comment: are you able to share a working example, so we can easily inspect the code?

Comment: Yes, sure.`Anydesk`? https://anydesk.com/remote-desktop @TemaniAfif

Comment: no, I meant something like https://jsfiddle.net or https://codepen.io

Comment: This is not pure css/html. It requires an Ionic framework. That is the issue there. @TemaniAfif

Comment: It is not working on `stackblitz` too: @TemaniAfif https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain `ima` element works for below `css`. But the same `css` doesn't work with `ion-img`. Maybe shadow dom issue or something else.

*Note:* If you know a better solution please put it.

*.html*

```
<img [src]="data?.path" class="image" />
```

*.scss*

```
 .image {
        height: 250px;
        width: 340px;
    }
```